# Misplaced noalign after rowcolor in multicolumn

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I want to use row coloring with `\multicolumn`. The MWE below works, but if I change 
to the commented, colored line, I receive a "misplaced \noalign". What do I wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{1.7cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.7cm}} %
\toprule
% \multicolumn{1}{>{\rowcolor{lightgray}}c}{}  &\multicolumn{7}{>{\rowcolor{lightgray}}c}{String length}\\
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  &\multicolumn{7}{c}{String length}\\
\rowcolor{lightgray} Function & 16,384 & 32,768& 65,536 & 130,072 & 262,144 & 524,288& 1,048,576\\
\midrule
lower1  & 0.19 & 0.77 & 3.08 & 12.24 & 49.39 & 198.42 & 791.22\\
lower2& 0.0000 &  0.0000 & 0.0001 & 0.0002 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0015\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I was experimenting with a solution like this, because I receive strange table heading, like below. The code you suggested works fine in MWE, but in my real text, with copy&paste from the answer, it produces the strange heading. Any idea, what can change the behavior?
[image]

Comment: Can you maybe accept an answer to mark the question as resolved, if any was helpful?

Answer (score 7):

`\rowcolor` are for rows and is used *at the beginning of a new row*. When using `\multicolumn`, you are technically referring to cells. So, use `\cellcolor`. Also, I would create a new `\toprule` and `\midrule` to combine the header colour with the rules.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl,xcolor}

\newcommand{\toprulec}{\arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{0.1em}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}
\newcommand{\midrulec}{\arrayrulecolor{lightgray}\specialrule{\aboverulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{white}\specialrule{\belowrulesep}{0pt}{0pt}%
            \arrayrulecolor{black}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{1.7cm} *{2}{p{1.3cm}} *{4}{p{1.35cm}} p{1.7cm} } %
  \toprulec
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{lightgray}} &\multicolumn{7}{c}{\cellcolor{lightgray}String length} \\
  \rowcolor{lightgray} Function & 16,384 & 32,768& 65,536 & 130,072 & 262,144 & 524,288& 1,048,576 \\
  \midrulec
  lower1  & 0.19 & 0.77 & 3.08 & 12.24 & 49.39 & 198.42 & 791.22\\
  lower2& 0.0000 &  0.0000 & 0.0001 & 0.0002 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0015\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

`\rowcolor` should be given at the start of a row, not in the way you're trying to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{1.7cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.3cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.35cm}p{1.7cm}}
\toprule
\rowcolor{lightgray}& \multicolumn{7}{c}{String length}\\
\rowcolor{lightgray}%
Function & 16,384 & 32,768& 65,536 & 130,072 & 262,144 & 524,288& 1,048,576\\
\midrule
lower1 & 0.19 & 0.77 & 3.08 & 12.24 & 49.39 & 198.42 & 791.22\\
lower2 & 0.0000 &  0.0000 & 0.0001 & 0.0002 & 0.0004 & 0.0008 & 0.0015\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the `\midrule`, which serves no purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I took the idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599879/rowcolor-on-a-multirow-tabular-in-latex

Comment: @katang That's for `\columncolor`, which is quite different.