# Misplaced \noalign when everything seems fine

Tags: tables

Working in overleaf, I get the error `Misplaced \noalign` but I can't seem to figure out why. Here's my code

```
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \cline{2-3} 
                \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \rowcolor{Gray} SEL0  & SEL1  \\ \hline
                \cellcolor{Gray} UART   & OFF                   & OFF   \\ \hline
                \cellcolor{Gray} SPI    & OFF                   & ON    \\ \hline
                \cellcolor{Gray} I2C    & ON                    & ON    \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{Communication module selection PN532 Breakout Board}
            \label{table:comModulePn532}
        \end{table}
```

The error comes from the line `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}   & \rowcolor{Gray} SEL0  & SEL1  \\ \hline`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Assuming that 1) you are using the `colortbl` package and 2) my memory is correct, the macro `\rowcolor` _must_ be used at the _start_ of a row.

Comment: ...indeed. From the [`colortbl`](//ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) (section **4 The `\rowcolor` command**): "It must be used at the *start* of a row."

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate): [Misplaced noalign after rowcolor in multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/231891/134144)

Comment: Thank you guys, it was a duplicate. I simply replaced \rowcolor with \cellcolor on the specific cells I wanted to color and it worked. And @StefanPinnow I will make sure to include those the next time I post something on here.